# Add text to empty spreadsheet cells using values from another spreadsheet (using Python)

Tags: python, excel, append

I want to add text to empty cells in a spreadsheet (Main Excel) using another spreadsheet (Reference Excel). When a certain (unique) string appears in the 'Code' Column of the Main Excel, I want to fill in the empty cells on that same row using values from another spreadsheet and that are associated with the same unique string.

My 'dictionary' spreadsheet (Reference Excel):

| Code | Country | Capital | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AU | Australia | Canberra | English |
| FR | France | Paris | French |
| US | USA | DC | English |

The spreadsheet I want to fill-in (Main Excel):

| Country | Capital | Language | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | AU |
|  |  |  | FR |
|  |  |  | US |

What python code can I write to enter the corresponding values to the Codes on the same row in the Main Excel? For example, when python sees "AU" in the Code Column of the Main Excel, I want python to add "Australia", "Canberra", and "English" (in that order) to the Country, Capital, and Language columns that are on the same row as "AU".

[The Main Excel I want to fill in, and the Reference Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxjSO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to do what you want.

```py
import pandas as pd


main = pd.read_excel('main.xlsx')
reference = pd.read_excel('reference.xlsx')

# Below are two methods to fill values in Main Excel
# with values from Reference Excel, you only need choose one

# 1. Using Series map
columns = ['Language', 'Country', 'Capital']
for column in columns:
    main[column] = main['Code'].map(reference.set_index('Code')[column])

# 2. Using Dataframe update
main = main.set_index('Code').update(reference.set_index('Code'))

# At last, write the filled main dataframe to new excel
main.to_excel('filled_main.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really awesome and simple! I also appreciate seeing both methods. I assume that if the Main Excel column titles are in another language (ex if Main is in French: Langue, Pay, Capitale) than the english column titles in the Reference Excel, then I would just change the list in the series map to be:columns = ['Langue', 'Pay', 'Capitale']